# Not a statement ; expected

Tags: java

Not a statement 
    ; expected

Im trying to put the value of the input into an array. But it says not a statement

Im new to programming and Im trying to learn java on my own

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] studID = new int[100];
        String[] Lname = new String[100];
        String[] Fname = new String[100];
        String[] studProgram = new String[100];
        int[] studYear = new int[100];


        System.out.println("1. add student");
        System.out.println("2. view student");
        System.out.println("3. edit student");
        System.out.println("4. delete student");
        System.out.print("Please choose: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = scan.nextInt();

        switch(choice){

            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
                studID[] = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter Last name: ");
                Lname[] = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter First name: ");
                Fname[] = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter Course: ");
                studProgram[] = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
                studYear[] = scan.nextInt();

            case 2:
                 System.out.println("Enter student ID to view: ");
                 int studView = scan.

        }
    } 
}
```

I expect that when I put the value of the student into the array, if I choose to view the student ID, it will also show the other information of the student that relies on the student ID

Comment: `int studView = scan.nextInt();` instead of `int studView = scan.`

Comment: `studID[] = scan.nextInt();` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Please note that you must indicate which line the error occurs on by copying the complete error text into your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can not assign an `int` to a whole Array

```
studID[] = scan.nextInt();
```

what you would need to do is assign it to one element of the array like

```
studID[0] = scan.nextInt();
```

or

```
studID[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

where `i` is the index

**BUT**

as you are not looping or using multiple values, why do you even have arrays?

Comment: so that when another user try to add a profile, it is not replaced

Comment: @Laiden Your code will only be executed one unless you have a loop

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you would likely be better off using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you're planning on adding integers to it dynamically. It doesn't require a pre-determined size and allows you to add an integer to the end of the array. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing couple of things wrong here.
Firstly, it should be like this. ; is expected to end the statement in java not a .(dot).

```
int studView = scan.nextInt();
```

Now, your logic for inserting array elements are not correct. As you must be knowing that arrays are collection of many elements that are stored at particular index. So, you need to store the elem from scan.nextInt() at a particular index. For that,

```
for(int i=0;i<someLength;i++){
 int choice = scan.nextInt();
  switch(choice){
   case 1:
        System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
            studID[i] = scan.nextInt(); // This i is important here to store at some particular index
   ......................
....................
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array to store a string or an integer given your code:

```
int[] studID = new int[100];
String[] Lname = new String[100];
String[] Fname = new String[100];
String[] studProgram = new String[100];
int[] studYear = new int[100];
```

Just declare them as like this :

```
int studID;
String Lname;
String Fname;
String studProgram;
int studYear;
```

And in this switch case :

```
switch(choice){

        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
            studID = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter Last name: ");
            Lname = scan.next();

            System.out.print("Enter First name: ");
            Fname = scan.next();

            System.out.print("Enter Course: ");
            studProgram = scan.next();

            System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
            studYear = scan.nextInt();


    }
```

The method nextInt() returns an integer, not an array and next() returns a string, not a string array. if you need any help we are more than happy to help you.